# Audi A1 makes a loud engine sound

Tags: engine, noise, audi, a1

I recently started hearing really loud noises coming from my engine. When I turn the engine on the noise is much louder then normal. When I open the hood to look at the engine I can see it is shaking slightly.  I have no engine lights coming up.

Can you please advise me regarding what the problem could be?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think a video of the engine bay is necessary for us to be able to help you. If you could upload it to somewhere like YouTube and edit the question to point us to the video that would be great

Comment: Have you checked the oil level lately?  Or changed the oil lately?

Comment: Does the engine sound change after you start driving? Any resonating or vibrations inside of the car that wasn't there before? If you let your car idle in park for 5 minutes, does the noise level decrease by itself?

Answer (score 1):

If it sounds like normal engine noise but louder the first suspect will be a leak in the exhaust system somewhere. Look for any evidence of black soot around the exhaust system or any obvious holes, cracks or other damage also that all of the various elements of the exhaust system are  connected properly.

If the sound is more metallic it could indicate something internal to the engine, a rattle is often associated with with valves.